# I have an exposed ceiling in the basement. Want to come off a daisy chain and connect 2 light fixtures and one independent switch

Tags: planning

I have 5 fluorescent lights connected in series two way switches. I want to jump out of the daisy chain to power two recessed LED lights and control only those two lights by a single light switch. When complete the daisy chain operators as it did from the two way switches and the two recesses light are controlled with one newly installed switch. The walls are insulated with foam and covered with drywall.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box where you plan to tap always-hot and neutral off at?